# Data processing within GroupBy objects. How to add columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'd like to take every pitcher's last pitch per game in an MLB dataset and mark it as True.  However, I'm having trouble adding columns or modifying the dataframe within a GroupBy object.  How could I effectively add this column?

```
data['last_pitch'] = False
g = data.groupby(['gameString', 'pitcherId'])
for x, pitcher in g:
    pitcher.iloc[-1]['last_pitch'] = True
```

Answer (score 1):

It's tempting to use `GroupBy` for this. However, there are often alternative methods when you aren't looking to actually aggregate data. Here, you can use [`pd.Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep='last'`:

```
# data from gyoza

df['last_pitch'] = ~df['pitcherId'].duplicated(keep='last')

print(df)

  gameString pitcherId  last_pitch
0          a         c       False
1          a         c        True
2          b         d       False
3          b         d       False
4          b         d        True
```

If you really wish to use `GroupBy`, you can use the `last` method:

```
idx = df.reset_index().groupby('pitcherId')['index'].last().values

df['last_pitch'] = df.index.isin(idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to find all the indices of the rows that you want to change with `tail` and then use `loc` to change them in the original dataframe:

```
last_rows = data.groupby(['gameString', 'pitcherId']).tail(n=1)
data.loc[last_rows.index, 'last_pitch'] = True
```